# How to create managed object in unmanaged C++ while wrapping it for JNA between Java and C#?

Tags: c#, java, visual-c++, new-operator, jna

I am trying to make a callback interface between C# and Java using JNA.

**C#**  <--CLI-->  **Visual C++ 2010**  <--JNA-->  **Java**

Between Java and C++ I am using unmanaged structures to get callback functionality. In C++ I am trying to wrap structure, that has callback pointers, into managed object.

Between Java and C++ everything works until I'm trying to use **gcroot** for managed object generation in unmanaged code.

***UPDATE*** it even fails without gcroot. Just with "Logger^ logger = gcnew Logger(logStruct);"

My current solution is as follows:

### Java

LoggerStruct.java

```java
package jnatest;

import com.sun.jna.Callback;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LoggerStruct extends Structure {
    private Logger logger;

    public interface GetLevelCallback extends Callback {
        int callback();
    }

    public GetLevelCallback getLevel;

    public LoggerStruct(Logger log) {
        super();
        this.log = log;

        getLevel = new GetLevelCallback() {
            public int callback() {
                return logger.getLevel().intValue();
            }
        }

        setFieldOrder(new String[] {"getLevel"});
    }
}
```

ITestLib.java

```java
package jnatest;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public interface ITestLib extends Library {
    ITestLib INSTANCE = (ITestLib) Native.loadLibrary("JNATestC", ITestLib.class);
    int callbackTest(LoggerStruct logStruct);
}
```

Main.java

```java
package jnatest;

import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("JNATestC", "C:\\JNATest");

        Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Test");
        FileHandler fileTxt = new FileHandler("Logging.txt");
        log.addHandler(fileTxt);

        LoggerStruct logStruct = new LoggerStruct(log);

        ITestLib.INSTANCE.callbackTest(logStruct);
    }
}
```

### C++

JNATestC.h

```cpp
#pragma once

extern "C" {
    struct LoggerStruct {
        int (*getLevel)();
    }
    __declspec(dllexport) void callbackTest(LoggerStruct * logStruct);
}

namespace JnaWrapperTypes {
    public ref class Logger { // "public ref" because I have to use it in C# as well
        private:
            LoggerStruct * logStruct;
        public:
            Logger(LoggerStruct * logStruct);
            ~Logger() {} 
            int getLevel();
    };
}
```

JNATestC.cpp

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vcclr.h>
#include "JNATestC.h"

namespace JnaWrapperTypes {
    Logger::Logger(LoggerStruct * logStruct) {
        this->logStruct = logStruct;
    }
    Logger::getLevel() {
        return logStruct->getLevel();
    }
}

using namespace JnaWrapperTypes;
using namespace StaticCSharpNamespace; // Just an example. Not existing C# lib.

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) void callbackTest(LoggerStruct * logStruct) {
        int level = logStruct->getLevel();

        gcroot<Logger^> logger = gcnew Logger(logStruct); // IF I ADD "gcroot" FOR "Logger" THEN WHOLE INVOKE FAILS
        level = logger->getLevel();

        StaticCSharpClass::staticMethod(logger); // I want to pass Managed object to C# later

        gcroot<System::String^> str = gcnew System::String(""); // This doesn't generate error
    }
}
```

I wrote these on the fly. I hope these validate as well.

**What am I doing wrong?** For example if I use...

```
gcroot<System::String^> str = gcnew System::String("");
```

...everything works just fine.

**Is there another way to pass managed object to C#?**

Log for this error [LOG](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/07WJ)

**UPDATE**

It seems that anykind of my own Class usage will head me to failure.

**UPDATE**

Anykind of my own Managed object or function use heads me to failure.

**UPDATE**

StaticCSharpClass::staticMethod(); fails as well. Looks like all operations related to Managed objects fail.

**UPDATE**

If I invoke the same method from .NET, everything works fine.

***just to make this problem more findable***
Internal Error (0xe0434352)

Comment: I think I have found the solution: http://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TDI-19427 Still GAC problem...what I assumed it is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should have googled for error "Internal Error (0xe0434352)".

http://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TDI-19427

It leads to point that I have to register the dll for GAC (Global Assembly Cache), because Java searches only GAC and Application Base directories for dll. And because Java.exe paths aren't configurable.

## == Solution ==

Use post build event to register assembly for GAC:

```
gacutil /i "$(TargetPath)"
```

Great monologue! =)